# Add AdWhirl view to a tabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, adwhirl, tabbarcontroller

I am trying to add an Adwhirl view to the top of my current iOS application. The application is composed of five different views, which are all under the control of a single TabBarController. can anyone write a brief tutorial that shows the code required to achieve this? I have looked through and tried a lot of the solutions out there but none of them are making it work.

Below is my current attempt at the problem, I don't get errors but I don't see anything different on the screen. Thanks in advance.

```
@implementation idoubs2AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize tabBarController;
@synthesize contactsViewController;
@synthesize messagesViewController;
@synthesize adwhirlview = adview;

static UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier sBackgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
static dispatch_block_t sExpirationHandler = nil;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

AdWhirlView *adView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:adView];
adView.center = CGPointMake(160, 342);
[self.tabBarController.view bringSubviewToFront:adView];
}

- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey {
// return your SDK key  
return kSampleAppKey;

}
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView {

//return UIWindow.viewController;
return [(idoubs2AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]     tabBarController];

}
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView {



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't be adding subviews to a normal UITabBar, if you need to customize the layout of your tab bar you might want to take a look at some of the replacements here: http://cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of adding subviews to a UITabBar, you may think of making something similar to a `GADBannerView` singleton that you could just then add to each o the `ViewControllers` that your `UITabBarController` contains.

So you can set up a singleton easily enough (there's another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699518/admod-single-instance-in-all-viewcontrollers/9705835#9705835) that talks about how to do this for AdMob ads and making it work with AdWhirl should be trivial).

Then just add some `ViewControllers` into your `UITabBarController` doing something like:

```
  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController"
                                        bundle:nil]
                                       autorelease];
  UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController"
                                        bundle:nil]
                                       autorelease];

  self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           viewController1,
                                           viewController2,
                                           nil];
```