# iAd/AdMob mediation, banner loading error?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I use 2 view controllers. Both VC's have the same exact code for iAd/AdMob mediation. My refresh rate in Admob is 30 seconds, can't set any lower. Can't find where to set a refresh rate for iAd network anywhere.

When my 1st VC in viewDidLoad loads an iAd then the 2nd VC automatically loads iAd within 5 seconds.

When my 1st VC in viewDidLoad loads an AdMob banner then the 2nd VC loads iAd or AdMob banner in around 30 seconds.

Does this have to do with the refresh rate I set in AdMob? 30 seconds is the minimum. But I don't understand why when iAd loads first, then the next ad loads quickly, but if AdMob loads first the next ad loads in 30 seconds. Is this typical or is there a code to make AdMob/iAd banner load within specific timeframe?

Comment: You should not use different banners for each view. Probably Apple will reject this anyways but besides this, what you want is a shared banner, a banner that is not attached to a certain view, instead it is "above all" so the banner does not change when user switches to another viewcontroller. this will give users longer chance to click it no matter how fast he navigates which will give you better clickrate and more money ;) you can achieve a shared banner by using a singleton class for the banner. also use a mediation network instead of mediate yourself by code.

Comment: use a shared banner in a singleton class, implement an admob banner with the admob framework, turn on mediation in the admob web interface and enable iAd there, don t put refeshrate less than 45 secs... to give people a chance to click an ad...

Comment: p.s. never ever click an admob banner yourself if it is a real ad and no test ad when you test your implementation !!! they ll ban you !

Comment: by the way interstitials (full screen ads) are paid much better and are really easy to implement. you don t need to worry about different VC.

Comment: this helps http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.de/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html

Comment: https://github.com/chrisjp/CJPAdController

Comment: I'm only using test ads. You mean if iAd loads on the first VC and then AdMob on the 2nd VC, apple would reject my app for that? Why?  I didn't know that. So I have to make it if on 1 VC an iAd loads then 2nd VC an iAd  loads and same with AdMob with AdMob only?

Comment: I'd like to add i am using mediation network, I'm using AdMob/iAd mediation. i'm only using banner ads, no pop ups. What do you mean by no test ads when i'm testing implementation? What do I use then?

Comment: "It is strongly recommended to use test ads while developing so you can test the ad click behavior." That's what it says on google's Admob guide part

Comment: You need one single banner that sits on top of all no matter which vc is shown, if vc changes the banner just stays caus it is not attached to a specific vc. Look at my links, you need a singleton class. You don t habe two banners in one single app.. So iad + iad or iad + admob or admob + admob is not the question... You need ONE banner that sits above all vc no matter which vc is shown...With test ads i mean, when iwas testing iwas shown real ads in simulator instead of test ads and if you click them you get banned by google.

Comment: "no test ad when you test your implementation" What do you mean by that part? If I don't use a test ad, what do i use?

Comment: Sure you need test ads. When i was testing, i was shown real ads instead of test ads, that s not good, don t know why this hapened to me.. If you are shown test ads all is good

Comment: Look at this and use ONE banner for all VC. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699518/admod-single-instance-in-all-viewcontrollers

Comment: So it's 100% necessary to ONLY use a singleton ad  for banners for all view controllers or else my app would get rejected by apple? So with a singleton banners it'd be 1 banner across all VC's but it'd be like 1 banner is all iAd and when iAd fails it'd be 1 banner is all AdMob?

Comment: i don't use UINavigationController or UITabBarController. CJPADController is designed for those 2. Is there any other way to mediate between admob/iad with singleton?

Comment: Add admob sdk, call a admob sdk banner in a singleton class, use this singleton for all VCs, enable mediation in admob web interface, and this ONE banner will mediate all ad networks for example iad that you enable in mediation... Just read the admob medition implementaion tutorial

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/mediation

Comment: Apple will probably reject if you don t use singleton, but anyways it s bad for you... User loads your app and gets shown ad in vc1 he navigates imidiatly to vc2 so ad in vc1 will never be clicked = bad clickrate = bad payment - so use one the same banner for all VCs. You can mediate as many networks in it as you like

Comment: I use 2  View Controllers for my game. So the code for a singleton class needs to be put in just the 1st view controller or both view controllers for it to work?